# How to generate huge random data and populate Elastic search running on K8S cluster?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kibana

I've K8S cluster up and running. There is Elastic search and Kibana deployed on the K8S cluster.
I need to populate ES with almost 25 t0 50GB of random data to Elastic search for testing. Any easy way to achieve this. I'm a newbie to ES and K8S. Any inputs or pointers will be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Logstash for ingesting data to the elasticsearch. Logstash supports various input plugins from elasticsearch log4j to S3. You can try ingesting data from any one of the sources that logstash supports as input plugin.
[https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/input-plugins.html][1]